# проблема TinyMCE + responsive filemanager

Tags: php, tinymce

День добрый! 
Был нужен WYSIWYG с менеджером файлов, естественно бесплатно такое добро нигде не лежит, по этому решил использовать TinyMCE и 3рд пати фаил менеджер, responsice fm (RFM).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Папка RFM лежит в корневой директории сайта, при открытии менеджера папки менеджер видит файлы тоже загружает, в редакторе вставляются все ок, но вот только когда пытаюсь создать файл или папку в RFM, ни папка ни файл не создаются, окно менеджера просто смаргивает и все (никаких ошибок ни в окне браузера ни в консоле не вылазит), если создать папку ручками то в менеджере она видна все! Кто знает где копать или как включить debug ? (Windows 8.1 + Open Server)

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#mytextarea",

        // ===========================================
        // INCLUDE THE PLUGIN
        // ===========================================

        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages responsivefilemanager"
        ],

        // ===========================================
        // PUT PLUGIN'S BUTTON on the toolbar
        // ===========================================

        toolbar: "responsivefilemanager | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | " +
                "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | " +
                "bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",


        external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "plugins/responsivefilemanager/plugin.min.js"},

        // ===========================================
        // SET RELATIVE_URLS to FALSE (This is required for images to display properly)
        // ===========================================

        relative_urls: false

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Ох, мои глаза. Пожалуйста, разбейте текст на предложения. А ещё неплохо бы увидеть код, которым вы работаете с RFM.

Comment: Добавил инфо, так думаю нагляднее будет

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с данной проблемой, может кому пригодится.
Это происходит из за каких-то ошибок в языковых файлах менеджера, можно решить двумя способами:

1. Проверить все языковые файлы, импортнуть недостающие.
2. Найти execute.php (лежит по пути: TinyMCE->responsive_filemanager->filemanager->execute.php)
   Найти в  execute.php

   ```
    if (isset($_SESSION['RF']['language_file']) && file_exists($_SESSION['RF' ['language_file']))
    {
    require_once $_SESSION['RF']['language_file'];
    }
    else
    {
    response(trans('Lang_Not_Found').AddErrorLocation())->send();
    exit;
    }
   ```

и законментить вот эти строчки

```
response(trans('Lang_Not_Found').AddErrorLocation())->send();
exit;
```